# How does Notoriety work?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have a wingmate who has had a notoriety level of 1 since last night. I've read on the [wiki](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Notoriety) that it decays by one point every 2 hours. Since he's still notorious a day later, I did some [research](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/409776-Significant-Notoriety-Issues) and found people saying:

- 2 hour time limit
- 2 hour time limit *from next login*
- indeterminate time / encountered a bug

Is there a way to see the remaining time on your notoriety level?

If not, is there a hard and fast rule (possibly from Fdev?) governing notoriety?

Are there any known quirks with it, e.g. do you have to jump to another system to start the 2 hour timer?

---

Edit:

The problem was actually a 5k bounty that he couldn't pay off until he was at notoriety 0. A quick fix was to buy a sidewinder and have another wingmate blow him up. He had notoriety 0 when he respawned, but still could not pay off the bounty. But, after logging out and back in, he was able to pay it off and became clean.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you immediate question: Post 3.0, you gain one point of notoriety for every murder (except for cases like murdering SpecOps targets in their USS) and lose one point every two hours being logged in; the countdown ticks while you remain in game... including just sitting in a station and being semi-afk(thanks @deathmagnet).

However, I have also encountered a bug (twice) where, being at 0 notoriety, the contact has refused to clear my bounty. The first time I just waited and it eventually let me pay my bounty. The second time I logged out and back in again and that also alleviated the issue. But neither of those times did I try to exploit the system by blowing up sidewinders ...

Comment: Sitting at a station afk does not work. at least not anymore. I just did it overnight. no change to notoriety.

Comment: @deathmagnet weird, it's not in the patch notes. Did you get kicked for inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

With the current state of the game and the regular udates to the Crime and Punishment system it is difficult to write a long lasting answer.

However, as an occasional criminal, it seems notoriety decreases every two hours while logged in as after spending weekends out of the game has not reduced my notoriety at all when long sessions have.

I have read a an article that pointed the same way but will have to find it again to link to it.

An interesting experiment to make would be if said two hours must be during the same session or can be split across several.